# MySql Data Cleanup with IF Else

Tags: mysql

```
IF (SELECT count(*) FROM clients) > 0 THEN
      ( TRUNCATE client_revisions ) 
ELSE
 ( DELETE FROM client_revisions WHERE client_id NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM clients))
END IF;
```

How my I write kind of query in raw MySQL?? is it possible?
I need it for data cleanup

Thanks

Comment: You should read about cascading deletion in MySQL.

Comment: You can Do it using stored procedures

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide table schema, sample data and details on what you are truing to clean/prune.